# How to add a document uploaded by a user in my app, to a docusign e-sign envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

In my application, a user can upload agreement docs that need to be sent to another party for signature. How can I add this uploaded document to a DocuSign envelope for e-signature. The uploaded docs are stored on S3 instance. One way I could figure from the documentation is to first create a draft envelope using makeEnvelope, and then add documents using the update documents API(https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/update/). Is there a way to add my documents while creating the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in the same `POST` call to `/envelopes` endpoint.
Not sure how you make API calls, but [this article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/) shows how to do that either with or without SDK in 8 languages.

The JSON body looks like this:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this document set",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "' > $request_data
            cat $doc1_base64 >> $request_data
            printf '",
            "name": "Order acknowledgement",
            "fileExtension": "html",
            "documentId": "1"
        },
        {
            "documentBase64": "' >> $request_data
            cat $doc2_base64 >> $request_data
            printf '",
            "name": "Battle Plan",
            "fileExtension": "docx",
            "documentId": "2"
        },
        {
            "documentBase64": "' >> $request_data
            cat $doc3_base64 >> $request_data
            printf '",
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "documentId": "3"
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "carbonCopies": [
            {
                "email": "'"${CC_EMAIL}"'",
                "name": "'"${CC_NAME}"'",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2"
            }
        ],
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "'"${SIGNER_EMAIL}"'",
                "name": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "anchorString": "**signature_1**",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "anchorString": "/sn1/",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```